# Difference between GetHostEntry and GetHostByName?

Tags: c#, dns, gethostbyname

On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.aspx) it mentions `GetHostByName` is obsolete. The replacement is `GetHostEntry`. What are their difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like GetHostEntry does a little more error checking and also supports [Network Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyb3xww8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

GetHostByName Decompiled:

```
public static IPHostEntry GetHostByName(string hostName)
{
  if (hostName == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("hostName");
  Dns.s_DnsPermission.Demand();
  IPAddress address;
  if (IPAddress.TryParse(hostName, out address))
    return Dns.GetUnresolveAnswer(address);
  else
    return Dns.InternalGetHostByName(hostName, false);
}
```

GetHostEntry Decompiled:

```
public static IPHostEntry GetHostEntry(string hostNameOrAddress)
{
  if (Logging.On)
    Logging.Enter(Logging.Sockets, "DNS", "GetHostEntry", hostNameOrAddress);
  Dns.s_DnsPermission.Demand();
  if (hostNameOrAddress == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("hostNameOrAddress");
  IPAddress address;
  IPHostEntry ipHostEntry;
  if (IPAddress.TryParse(hostNameOrAddress, out address))
  {
    if (((object) address).Equals((object) IPAddress.Any) || ((object) address).Equals((object) IPAddress.IPv6Any))
      throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString("net_invalid_ip_addr"), "hostNameOrAddress");
    ipHostEntry = Dns.InternalGetHostByAddress(address, true);
  }
  else
    ipHostEntry = Dns.InternalGetHostByName(hostNameOrAddress, true);
  if (Logging.On)
    Logging.Exit(Logging.Sockets, "DNS", "GetHostEntry", (object) ipHostEntry);
  return ipHostEntry;
}
```

Comment: If you find yourself with those obsolete error just like myself, you can just easily change `GetHostByName()` with `GetHostEntry()` on your code.

Comment: It's not quite that straightforward. `GetHostByAddress` will fail even on a valid IP if it cannot perform a reverse DNS lookup. As a rough rule of thumb, it looks like the front-end `GetHostEntry` aims to only return _actual DNS entries_, whereas `GetHostByName` aims to supply an IP address any way it can. So, any IP address you pass to `GetHostByName` will simply be parsed and returned, but `GetHostEntry` will only give you back that IP _if you can get a reverse DNS response for it_. This makes `GetHostEntry` less suitable for general purpose handling of target addresses from user input.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it is important to recognize that these are wrappers of the UNIX socket library, which exposes functions `inet_aton` (equivalent to `IPAddress.Parse`), `gethostbyname` (wrapped by `Dns.GetHostByName`) and `gethostbyaddr` (wrapped by `Dns.GetHostByAddress`). Microsoft subsequently added the `Dns.GetHostEntry` utility function based on these.

After pondering the philosophical difference between `Dns.GetHostByName` and `Dns.GetHostEntry`, I've come to the conclusion that Microsoft decided that the primary API they expose for DNS lookups should be trying to return only *actual DNS entries*.

At the UNIX sockets level, `gethostbyname` can take either an IP address or a host name. It is explicitly documented as parsing the IP address if that's what you supply. But it is also explicitly documented as only supporting IPv4 addresses. As such, developers are encouraged to use the function `getaddrinfo` instead, which does a more complex look-up involving the service you want to connect to as well, and which supports address families other than IPv4.

Microsoft took a different approach in their wrapper. They still consider `GetHostByName` to be deprecated, but instead of tying the look-up to a services database, they decided to create a function that returns the actual physical DNS host entry you ask for. It's not enough that you perhaps supply a string with a valid address in it, if there's no DNS entry then `GetHostEntry` will fail, because that is its entire purpose. Thus, if you pass a host name into `GetHostEntry`, it performs a forward DNS lookup, and if you pass an IP address into `GetHostEntry`, it performs a reverse DNS lookup. Either way, the returned structure will tell you both the DNS entry name and the associated address -- *but* if there is no associated entry, the only thing you get back is an error.

If you're looking to handle user input that supplies a target for connection, `GetHostEntry` is not really suitable, because if the user types in an ad hoc IP address, it may fail to resolve it even though, since it's an IP address, you have everything you need to make a connection. `GetHostByName` is exactly the function you need in this case, but Microsoft have chosen to deprecate it. Given the deprecation, the idiom is going to be to replicate the "try to parse first" approach that @Faisai Mansoor showed in the decompiled `GetHostByName` function:

```
// Microsoft's internal code for GetHostByName:
if (IPAddress.TryParse(hostName, out address))
  return Dns.GetUnresolveAnswer(address);
else
  return Dns.InternalGetHostByName(hostName, false);
```

This uses internal implementation details of the `Dns` class, but the spirit of it is easy to replicate in your own code, e.g.:

```
if (!IPAddress.TryParse(userInput, out var addressToWhichToConnect))
  addressToWhichToConnect = Dns.GetHostEntry(userInput).AddressList.First();
```